# Textblock Text property not being set using OnLoaded event

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, events, textblock

I Have a texblock on a specific page. I am navigation from a previous page where one a selection from a listbox is clicked, the object is stored the the APP.Xaml file as a property. On my navigating page, i call this object in the Loaded event for my listboxes and set their text property to their respective equivalents on my stored property from my App.xaml file.

The problem is, only one of 4 listboxes works while the other fail to show up. Anyone know why this may be. My code is below.

```
 private void StopNameTextBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StopNameTextBlock.Text = (Application.Current as App).SelectedBusStop.StopName;
    }

    private void BusDirectionTextBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {   
        BusDirectionTextBlock.Text = "Towards: " + (Application.Current as App).SelectedBusStop.BusDirection;
    }

    private void BusesServedTextBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BusesServedTextBlock.Text = "Buses Served: " + (Application.Current as App).SelectedBusStop.BusesServed;
    }
```

From the code above. the first text block populates but the others do not. Help
Below is the XAML code.

```
<StackPanel Name="StopInfo" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,620">
            <TextBlock Name="BusDirectionTextBlock" Loaded="BusDirectionTextBlock_Loaded" />
            <TextBlock Name="BusesServedTextBlock" Loaded="BusesServedTextBlock_Loaded" />
            <TextBlock Name="TimeRequestedTextBlock" />
        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: This is not the way to do things in XAML based technologies. You need to create a `ViewModel` with the appropiate properties and bind your View to that.

Comment: I agree With @HighCore You Need To Create ViewModel And Bind Propery with that Control

Comment: Could you post the XAML of the page which contains the text blocks?

Comment: By view model do u mean a xaml page cus i do have one established

Comment: @SaniYusuf you need to learn [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) before you can use any of the XAML-based technologies (WPF / Silverlight / WinRT).

Comment: But regardless you are missing the point here. What im saying is it can be done the way i am doing it currently even doe it may not be the best way . Ca u point me to a temporary solution?

Comment: @SaniYusuf Im not missing the point. Your code is wrong and you need to delete it and start over using MVVM. I cannot tell you how to fix an incorrectly implemented solution.

Comment: Although MVVM may be considered best practice, it is entirely possible to code for silverlight without using it, or even DataBinding etc., at all. Sani, could you also post the part of the XAML where you declare the event for `StopNameTextBlock_Loaded` ?

Comment: Thanx @BolucPapuccuoglu > I have fixed the problem . Apparently it has always been set but i could not see it because i did not correctly position my grid elements so in my case my first big textblock was overlapping the others

Comment: @HighCore, you should be very careful when saying that code is wrong. I wouldn't not implement it this way either, but in the end it's really a matter of philosophy and judgement.

Comment: @MEMark no it's not. It's a matter of technical, objective code quality that has nothing to do with philosophy. Putting a bunch of untestable, non reusable code full of casts `((Thing)thing)` code which is prone to all sorts of runtime errors is quantifiably and objectively worse than having a strongly-typed, testable, reusable ViewModel.

Comment: @HighCore. IMHO every statement of the form "Your code is wrong and you need to delete it and start over using {insert favourite pattern here}" is by definition subjective. You could possibly argue that there's a certain universal minimum acceptable code quality level, but then that very level would be highly debatable. You may choose to optimize for speed, size, resource allocation, testability and/or readability. And whatever you choose someone will disagree with you on good grounds. I'll go as far as "There are better preferred ways of doing this".

Comment: @HighCore, No offence, but then I haven't even touched on the subject of what a harsh dismissive statement would do to an upcoming programmer, or what attitudes creates a permissive forgiving Stack Overflow atmosphere.

Comment: High Guys This Is Not An Argument. I Agree With @MemMark. I know how to use MVVM now but saying this was wrong is not correct. The is no wrong or right way to do things as long as they work. There is recommended and best practice ways. If this way was wrong firstly the language wouldnt allow it. SO guys I think its best we try to answer the questions and recommend best practices instead of automatically saying code os wrong or right after all we are all here to learn and become better.